# How to replace an array with an array of different shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to replace the values of an array with another array of a different shape.

```
a = np.array([[0,1],
              [0,0,1]])

b = np.array([[0. 0. 0.],
              [0. 0. 0.]])
```

I tried

```
b[0, :2] = a[0]
b[1,:] = a[1]
```

which works, but not the best for larger arrays.

I want

```
c = [[0,1,0],
     [0,0,1]]
```

Edit: Unless there is a way for an array to be filled with any value we could specify so that the array has the same shape as b. For example my array 'a' can become

```
[[0,1,nan],[0,0,1]]
```

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense because `a` here isn't a 2-d array. It's a 1-d array of python lists. That's fundamentally different from an "array of a different shape." (I'm kind of surprised that `numpy` doesn't just throw an error on that input!)

Comment: @senderle What do you mean it's not 2D? I'm new to numpy and I tested ```print(type(a))``` and it resulted in ```<class 'numpy.ndarray'>``` Does that mean ```b``` is also not 2D?

Comment: After a bit of searching, I realised they're meant to have a fixed dimension ie. homogenous and would be considered a 1D array of lists otherwise, as you said. Thanks